# Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException null is not an object (evaluating 'n[u]')

Tags: react-native

I have a project in React-native 0.60 with Redux-Saga and I have received a crash for Android in Google Firebase Crashlytics:

> Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException
>   null is not an object (evaluating 'n[u]'), stack: value@2368:3930 onSubmit@2368:1144 F@1737:580 @1700:5717 touchableHandlePress@205:2200 touchableHandlePress@-1 _performSideEffectsForTransition@189:9693 _performSideEffectsForTransition@-1 _receiveSignal@189:8375 _receiveSignal@-1 touchableHandleResponderRelease@189:5663 touchableHandleResponderRelease@-1 E@90:1233 z@90:1376 U@90:1430 D@90:1721 H@90:2497 forEach@-1 j@90:2297 @90:13831 Ue@90:81479 Me@90:13499 Fe@90:13672 receiveTouches@90:14441 value@31:3518 @31:822 value@31:2772 value@31:794 value@-1

It is a large project and I can't put some code here because I don't know what causes it and I searched in the path and I found out that **"n[u]"** is in **index.android.bundle**